# HERE CompositeFragment MAP Cannot initialize engine twice

Tags: android, here-api

I fully copied this code from HERE's official start-guide pdf, but when I try to run it, it fails on the `componentFragment.init()` with an `UNKNOWN` error.

**error Details:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize the engine twice
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.<init>(MapsEngine.java:604)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:897)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:394)
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:346)
    at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:129)
    at com.nokia.maps.al.a(CompositeFragmentImpl.java:92)
    at com.here.android.mpa.ar.CompositeFragment.init(CompositeFragment.java:108)
    at hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity.init(BasicMapActivity.java:106)
    at hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(BasicMapActivity.java:97)
    at hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity.checkPermissions(BasicMapActivity.java:80)
    at hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity.onCreate(BasicMapActivity.java:58)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

**BasicMapActivity.java**

```
package hu.appz4.heretest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.Manifest.permission;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARController;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARController.Error;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARIconObject;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.CompositeFragment;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.Image;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BasicMapActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * permissions request code
     */
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1000;

    /**
     * Permissions that need to be explicitly requested from end user.
     */
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                                          Manifest.permission.CAMERA, permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                                                                          permission.INTERNET};
    private Map               map;
    private ARController      arController;
    // buttons which will allow the user to start LiveSight and add objects
    private Button            startButton;
    private Button            stopButton;
    private Button            toggleObjectButton;
    // ARIconObject represents the image model which LiveSight accepts for display
    private ARIconObject      arIconObject;
    private boolean           objectAdded;
    private CompositeFragment compositeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
    }

    /**
     * Checks the dynamically-controlled permissions and requests missing permissions from end user.
     */
    protected void checkPermissions() {
        final List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        // check all required dynamic permissions
        for (final String permission : REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS) {
            final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            // request all missing permissions
            final String[] permissions = missingPermissions.toArray(new String[missingPermissions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            final int[] grantResults = new int[REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS, REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int index = permissions.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // exit the app if one permission is not granted
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission '" + permissions[index] + "' not granted, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // all permissions were granted
                init();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Search for the composite fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        compositeFragment = (CompositeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.compositefragment);
        compositeFragment.init(this, new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the composite fragment
                    map = compositeFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center to the Vancouver Downtown region
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(47.529877, 19.032750, 0.0), Map.Animation.NONE);
                    // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                    // LiveSight setup should be done after fragment init is complete
                    setupLiveSight();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BasicMapActivity.this, "ERROR: Cannot initialize Composite Fragment" + " - " + error.getDetails(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Composite Fragment" + " - " + error.getDetails());
                }
            }
        });
        // hold references to the buttons for future use
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startLiveSight);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopLiveSight);
        toggleObjectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleObject);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                startLiveSight(v);
            }
        });
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                stopLiveSight(v);
            }
        });
        toggleObjectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                toggleObject(v);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupLiveSight() {
        // ARController should not be used until fragment init has completed
        arController = compositeFragment.getARController();
        // tells LiveSight to display icons while viewing the map (pitch down)
        arController.setUseDownIconsOnMap(true);
        // tells LiveSight to use a static mock location instead of the devices GPS fix
        arController.setAlternativeCenter(new GeoCoordinate(47.529877, 19.032750, 0.0));
    }

    public void startLiveSight(View view) {
        if (arController != null) {
            // triggers the transition from Map mode to LiveSight mode
            Error error = arController.start();
            if (error == Error.NONE) {
                startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error starting LiveSight: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ArController NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void stopLiveSight(View view) {
        if (arController != null) {
            // exits LiveSight mode and returns to Map mode
            Error error = arController.stop(true);
            if (error == Error.NONE) {
                startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error stopping LiveSight: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void toggleObject(View view) {
        if (arController != null) {
            if (!objectAdded) {
                if (arIconObject == null) {
                    final Image image = new Image();
                    try {
                        image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // creates a new icon object which uses the same image in up and down views
                    arIconObject = new ARIconObject(new GeoCoordinate(47.529877, 19.032750, 2.0), (View) null, image);
                }
                // adds the icon object to LiveSight to be rendered
                arController.addARObject(arIconObject);
                objectAdded = true;
                toggleObjectButton.setText("Remove Object");
            } else {
                // removes the icon object from LiveSight, it will no longer be renderedarController.removeARObject(arIconObject);
                objectAdded = false;
                toggleObjectButton.setText("Add Object");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.Gradle dependencies (imported the official HERE-sdk.aar following the steps from guide.pdf)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':HERE-sdk')
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="hu.appz4.heretest"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <!-- Additional permission for LiveSight
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity
            android:name="hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="the app id from HERE site"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="the app code from HERE site"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
            android:value="the license key from HERE site"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hu.appz4.heretest.BasicMapActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.here.android.mpa.ar.CompositeFragment"
        android:id="@+id/compositefragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startLiveSight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="startLiveSight"
        android:text="@string/label_button_startlivesight" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopLiveSight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="stopLiveSight"
        android:text="@string/label_button_stoplivesight"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggleObject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="toggleObject"
        android:text="@string/label_button_addobject" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its may be some how your init() method is getting called twice. and here map will not initialize twice unless and until its single ton class. 
Make CompositeFragment singleton it will solve your issue.

Comment: Do you have set proper app id, app code and license key in **manifest file**

Comment: In debug mode, the compositeFragment.init() only called once and I cannot reach the inside code since it's decoded by HERE.

Comment: @AkashPatel yes it's properly defined, and I know that because at first I got the error for missing license key, but I solved that and this is the new error.

Comment: @Kiskunk please add manifest file code too and add "here-api" tag in your question so their support member can help you.

Comment: @AkashPatel thanks I'm not allowed to add here-api tag, but I put in the manifest (keys censored)

Comment: @Kiskunk did you try un-install the app and than re-install the app?

Comment: @AkashPatel not just that, but restarting adb, restarting android studio, creating an entirely new project etc. also tried compiling to api 16 through 25, neither worked, tested on android 4.4, 5.0.1, 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally managed to solve it by adding this code to the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
    android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="HereMapService"
    android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"/>
      </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: The service is needed to download and share access to the map store. Unfortunately there was a bug in v3.3.0 which did not correctly report initialization errors. This is now fixed in v3.3.1.

Comment: @DavidLeong when will release v3.3.1?

Comment: Soon. It should fix the error reported here. Instead of some exception it should report "missing service"

Answer (score 0):

In marshmallow you need to add 4 permission and your map will working fine

```
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE);
    int FourthPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    int SecondPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int ThirdPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

use this link for permission

[Request Check Multiple Run time Permissions at once in android Marshmallow](http://www.android-examples.com/request-check-multiple-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow/)

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (compositeFragment != null){
        try {
            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(compositeFragment).commit();
        }catch (Exception exONDestroyView){
            System.out.println(exONDestroyView);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (compositeFragment != null){
        try {
           this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(compositeFragment).commit();
        }catch (Exception exONDestroy){
            System.out.println(exONDestroy);
        }
    }

}
```

add two method in your activity Hope this help

Comment: ops Sorry ... was in Hurry  :)

Comment: No problem there.